# Careers: What does "allows remote" mean?

Tags: support, jobs

When a posting is marked "allows remote", does it mean work in the office some days, work from home some days?

Or does it mean you could actually live out of town and maybe fly in as needed?

The reason I ask is I'm really interested in public facing software rather than internal/enterprise stuff, and most of that seems to happen in a few very expensive cities.

Given it's so hard to hire in places like SV/NYC, it seems like it could be a good scenario for companies if a developer had a really solid list of accomplishments, but I don't know how many companies think this way.

Comment: You have to ask whoever posted it job listing. "allows remote" is an ambiguous term that can mean either of those. (although in my experience it's normally the former)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The instruction that we give to employers is that they should only indicate ‘remote’ if *full-time remote* is a possibility for the position. Beyond that, however, the policies would need to be discussed between the candidate and the employer.

Agree that there are multiple arrangements that are possible, and that ‘allows remote’ is not very specific. We’re looking at making the definition of ‘remote’ a bit more granular.

Added: if you feel that a particular listing is misleading in this regard, there’s a ‘flag’ link on the right-hand side.

Comment: I'd like to add something - There should be a clear "Allows overseas" flag. Currently, you have to specifically ask everyone, as most companies don't realize their postings are seen outside of the US. (Let me know if you think this is worthy of a separate feature request)

Comment: @Matt Sherman - Any progress on making "remote" more granular?  I'm frequently seeing adverts flagged as "allows remote" but where the textual job description (after careful reading) clearly states that _full-time_ remote is out of the question and that the employer expects the employee to be in the office at least some days per week, every week.  Perhaps we need "Allows full-time remote" and "Allows part-time remote" options with an additional qualifier for the "Allows part-time remote" option?