# Allows remote / Work remotely

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs

Searching for a job on SO Careers, you can check the *Allows remote* option. Then, all listed results will show a **WORK REMOTELY** sort-of tag.

Are both expressions synonyms or do they have a slightly different meaning?

And how can I distinguish those jobs where I can "sometimes" work from home from those ones where I can live, for instance, in another country?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, listings should only tag themselves as "allows remote" if that is available as a full time option (e.g. in a different country).

Comment: This answer should cover your question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173109/careers-what-does-allows-remote-mean?rq=1